# Pandas DateTimeIndex producing float instead of integer

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have the following code which creates a new column (cs_year) with just the year in it from the filedate column which is dtype datetime.  The resulting column dtype is a float.  Cannot figure out why this is happening and how to make the resulting column dtype into an integer.

```
df['cs_year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['filedate']).year
```

I tried simply using astype('int') to change the resulting column dtype into integer, but consistently get the following error when attempting that.

```
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

I have scanned the data to see if there is an errant value in the column, NA or some such other defect, nothing there.  Any ideas?

FYI, this is the code I used to convert the filedate column to datetime format.

```
df['filedate'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['filedate'], infer_datetime_format=True, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: If you need to use `errors="coerce"`, most likely you have NaN somewhere.

Comment: @HenryYik I was guessing that too, but cannot locate any in the list of data.  It's perplexing.  Perhaps I walk it back and replace NaN values with something and then convert to datetime to avoid this?  Is there a way to do the conversion and have the code display all row numbers in which errors are found?  That would be very helpful.  I could locate those errors, fix those dates and drive on.

Comment: Perhaps do a `fillna(0)` to fill it up so you can cast into `int`. And also why did you have to use `pd.DatetimeIndex`? Could simply do `df["filedate"].dt.year`.

Comment: @HenryYik The filedate column was dtype object, so it never occurred to me to just grab the year in that way.  I will try that as well as fillna to somehow squash that errant column value.